# How can I call an endpoint in my appengine instance without doing oAuth? (Mirror API)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, jinja2, google-mirror-api

I am trying to create some Glassware with the Mirror API. I am new to using AppEngine and Jinja2. I have python experience but never with a web framework before. So basically I am very new at this.

I have modified the Python quickstart for the mirror API to include many of my endpoints and designs. Basically I want to be able to be able to POST data from a constrained device to Glass. I have an endpoint all setup which works to accept and parse out the data and send the timeline item.

My problem is that the device itself is acting all on it's own and cannot provide input, therefore when I call my app from it e.g. `https://foo.appspot.com?operation=deviceData` the app presents the auth page and then nothing happens. I can see in the logs that the auth page is being sent, but the device has no idea what to do with this.

Basically, I need a way where I can hardcode credentials and get around having to do oauth everytime. What is the recommended way to do this? Another app which doesn't require auth which passes the data along? This would be fine as I only need to set this up with one user right now, it is for an internal demo only.

Is it possible to set my credentials in a header and auth automatically without handling any return, more like how basic auth works?

There are also the "Simple API access" keys. Would these work in this situation, I tried creating browser and server keys and tried them on the device and in the browser by doing`https://foo.appspot.com?operation=deviceData&key=KEY_HERE` but in both cases I was still prompted to login. Is this what simple access keys are for? Do they not work with the mirror API?

Basically my question is, what's the easiest way to allow access to my apps endpoints without having to oAuth or having a hard coded user which auto-auths?

Here is the project that I started with: https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python

Comment: Could you provide the url to the Python sample code you followed?

Comment: Its the mirror-python-quickstart example: https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python